# Get Instagram Access Token using Restful Ruby

Tags: ruby, rest, instagram-graph-api

I am trying to use the Instagram API to create a rails background worker to query hashtags. I don't need to log in any other user but myself furthermore I don't want to have to use any browsers, just RESTful calls.

I'm trying to automate getting my access token in a Ruby script using the gem "rest-client" (https://github.com/rest-client/rest-client)

I can successfully navigate to the following url in a browser and get the access token from the response url

I have used both this URL:
https://www.instagram.com/oauth/authorize/?client_id=xxx&redirect_uri=xxx&response_type=token

BUT When I use the RESTful gem `response = RestClient.get(url)` the 
`response.headers['location']` is nil

I have also tried using the Instagram API URL but no luck: https://api.instagram.com/oauth/authorize/?client_id=xxx&redirect_uri=xxx&response_type=code

Anyone know how to get the access token completely programmatically in Ruby?

I think I'm missing the step to log in the user (which will be me). Not sure how to do this programatically.

Can I use the instagram API with a code or access token that never changes?

Comment: Use [Instagram API](https://www.instagram.com/developer/authentication/).

Answer (score 0):

rest-client automatically request to get to redirect host.

https://github.com/rest-client/rest-client/blob/master/lib/restclient/abstract_response.rb

I have never used the instagram API yet, but the code to get "Location" on 302 is shown below.

```
# client
require 'net/http'
require 'uri'
url = URI.parse('http://localhost:2000')
res = Net::HTTP.start(url.host, url.port) do |http|
  http.get('/')
end
puts "#{res.header['Location']} is https://google.com"
```

```
# test server
require 'socket'
server = TCPServer.new 2000
loop do
  socket = server.accept
  while header = socket.gets
    break if header.chomp.empty?
    puts header.chomp
  end
  socket.puts "HTTP/1.0 302"
  socket.puts "Location: https://google.com"
  socket.close
end
```

I hope that this information is helpful to you.